Environment variable in Niginx or using phpdotenv
I am trying to save api authorization key (sensitive information) in an environment variable. I used fastcgi_param inside location ~ .php$ in Nginx configuration. I am calling this variable inside function.php file in wordpress to use the api. Is this secure or should i use phpdotenv php package and create .env file to define the variable. Thanks
Nginx:
 location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param API_AUTH 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
     }

Function.php
$auth = $_SERVER['API_AUTH'];


This question will likely be closed as opinion-based. The secureness of either method depends completely on your configuration. I prefer .env for a number of reasons. Most notably, the web server config should be separate from the app config, and this value should be changeable without needing root or having to restart nginx.

Thank you for your input. I am a beginner, and it is becoming extremely difficult for me to find a suitable solution

If you need to change values more often then a .env is easier as you can config this in your application instead of the server configuration.
